# For-loop inside foreach() in R

Tags: r, for-loop, foreach

Suppose we have the following data set named `data1`.

```
id  v1  v2
1   5   0.5
1   4   0.5
1   6   0.5
2   2   0.2
2   3   0.2
2   7   0.2
```

My intention is to do an analysis on each data created after subsetting `data1` by `id`. The following is my unsuccessful code.

```
library(parallel)
library(foreach)
library(doSNOW)

data2 <- list()
foreach(i = 1:length(unique(data1$id))) %dopar% {
  data2[i] <- subset(data1,data1$id==unique(data1$id)[i])
  a <- matrix(ncol = 3, nrow = length(data2[i]$v1)
   for (j in 1:length(data2[i]$v1)) {
         for (k in 1:3) {
            a[j,k] <- 1.5*data2[i]$v2
          }
      }
   return(a)
  }
```

Any help is highly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: I recommend figuring this out without parallelization first. But one thing I do not follow is ```xy[j, k] <- 1.5 * data2[i]$v2```. For this dataset in the first id group, that would translate to ```1.5 * c(0.5, 0.5, 0.5)``` which would be incorrect to assign back to a single element.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. That's the incorrect line of code.

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for `split()`? This function will separate your single data frame into a list of data frames, according to the distinct values of the second parameter.  Here is an example:

```
# Create sample data
data1 <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = '
id  v1  v2
1   5   0.5
1   4   0.5
1   6   0.5
2   2   0.2
2   3   0.2
2   7   0.2')

# Split data into separate data frames
lst <- split(data1, data1$id)

# View resulting list
lst
# $`1`
# id v1  v2
# 1  1  5 0.5
# 2  1  4 0.5
# 3  1  6 0.5
# 
# $`2`
# id v1  v2
# 4  2  2 0.2
# 5  2  3 0.2
# 6  2  7 0.2
```

Once in a list, you can usually send that into an analysis either directly or with an apply function.